# Generate equal distanced sections on polygon

Tags: r, polygon, polyline-creation

I generated a polygon by buffering a reference line. What I want to do now is generating multiple equal-distanced points along the reference lines, upon which to generate sections on the polygon. A sketch map is here:
[image]

## EDIT:

polygon data: [polygon data link](https://livejohnshopkins-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/hmi1_jh_edu/Ef6KOPgeZe1Dl3qYT7DHqPkBJledANfV-hBa1JIbCHyRow?e=3ybQyo)
reference line data: [reference line link](https://livejohnshopkins-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/hmi1_jh_edu/EauYdu3xashHs6oxFn9Z8nUBdHO0S9OWeKeUTyFCj-X-pA?e=eYPmX6)

Comment: Have you got some sample data? How bendy are your polygons? Have you had some thoughts of your own on how you might do this?

Comment: My thought is first identify multiple equal distanced points along the reference line, then draw perpendicular lines which go through these points to the reference line, and the sections could be obtained by calculating the intersections of perpendicular lines and the polygon.

Comment: @Spacedman I added links for the data so that you could reproduce the reference line and polygon, thank you!

Comment: Could you generate the parts by first splitting the line into small segments and then buffering those with "FLAT" endcap styles instead of creating a big buffer polygon and chopping that?

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to generate those equal-distanced segments along the line